# Replacing string with other string

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, replace

In line((s) that originate from csv file)

```
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500]http://map1.link.de/mk
```

what is the easiest part to replace/delete&add

```
]http://map1.link.de/
```

with

```
,
```

having in mind that after `map` can come any number `map1, map2, map3`

Example of couple of lines:

```
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500]http://map1.link.de/mk
14/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500]http://map5.link.de/mk
```

Final result

```
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500,mk
14/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500,mk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)].*\/\(.*$\)/\1,\2/' csv
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500,mk
14/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500,mk
```

Where `csv` is this file:

```
cat csv 
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500]http://map1.link.de/mk
14/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500]http://map5.link.de/mk
```

Explanation:
`\(.*\)]` = search and **save** every char until the first `[`
`.*\/` = after that, search - do **not** save - everything until the last `/`
`\(.*$\)` = **save** everything after that until the end of line (`mk`)
`\1,\2` = replace with what we saved and add a comma in between

Comment: Thanks! It works, so I am perfectly fine with sed. Can you please give me some sort of explanation, me and regex are not best friends!

Comment: @newbie_girl No problem. Regular expressions are hard, but even harder to explain in non-geek words!

Answer (score 0):

You can express sequence of one or more decimal digits POSIXly as `[0-9]\{1,\}` or less portably using the extended regular expression operator `+` as `[0-9]+` so either

```
sed 's@]http://map[0-9]\{1,\}\.link\.de/@,@' file.csv
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500,mk
14/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500,mk
```

or

```
sed -E 's@]http://map[0-9]+\.link\.de/@,@' file.csv
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500,mk
14/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500,mk
```

If you want to replace *any* URI (not just ones whose qualified hostname matches `map?.link.de`) then you can simplify the latter to

```
$ sed -E 's@]http://[^/]*/@,@' file.csv
14/Feb/2016:15:21:33-0500,mk
14/Feb/2016:16:21:33-0500,mk
```